# Bridge edge loops causing distotion in my mesh

Tags: modeling

I am following a tutorial and I bridged 2 edge loops and it is causing the geometry to appear distorted. I have attached the file as well - https://pasteall.org/blend/48bb216ac48045c6a4a134a03a22fd75 I would like to know what causes this.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: it looks like inverted normals, try to select all and Shift N

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like inverted normals, try to select all and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>